# using mongodb for flask session without proper index causes session update failure

Tags: mongodb, flask, session, pymongo, flask-session

If there are no index, session update doesn't seem to work and login fails.
After setting index for id field, everything works fine.
I wonder is this because response ended the thread and killed the mongo connnection?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error when Sessions tried to update mongo.

```
line 456, in save_session
    self.store.update({'id': store_id},
```

Turns out it was because the update method it was calling doesn't exist after pymongo v4.0.
I downgraded with

```
pip install pymongo:3.12.3
```

And now I have sessions stored in mongo :)